# PHP Laravel 6 - Profile Image Not Displaying

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-6

Im currently designing a website using the laravel framework for PHP. I am working on a profile page at the moment, that all fields are connected to their respected column in a database. They are updating okay but whenever a user changes their image from the default to a selected one, it just displays an empty box. Here is my code for review and would really appreciate some outside input.
PS: I do have the intervention Image extension added correctly

Profile.blade.php:

```
 <div class="card-header">
                <img src="/uploads/avatars/{{$user->avatar}}" style="width:100px; height:100px; float:left;
                margin-right:25px">
                <strong>{{$user->name}}'s Profile</strong></div>
```

ProfileController.php:

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['name' => 'required','email' => 'required|email']);
        $user = Auth::user();

        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->about = $request->about;
        $user->save();

        if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
            $avatar = $request->avatar;
            $avatar_new = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();//Creates unique name for file 
            Image::make($avatar)->resize(300,300)->save(public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $avatar_new));
            $user->avatar = $avatar_new;
            $user->save();
        return redirect()->back();

            }
```

***EXTENSION:***
Now for some reason when i try to update my user image i am met with this error

````
 Intervention\Image\Exception\NotSupportedException
GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.```



Even though it was at least updating only 15 minutes ago.
````

Comment: Well what does that URL return? Is it a 404?

Comment: No. The profile page redirects as expected and updates in the database. Just the image field is now a transparent box rather than the selected image.

Comment: So it returns a 200 with a transparent image?

Comment: Are u on a live server or on a local server? If u are on a live server u need to do some modification for the image to display.

Comment: Using docker to run on localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

Hello in your Controller that save your images you need the implementation of image with the store image in storage folder, that help you to upload images and laravel will save it in the storage images and that will be access in the public storage.

So what you need ?

go to [here is that you need to store images in folder storage and the link of the url on your database](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#introduction)

you are also need to store your image in your controller like this :

```
public fucntion create(Request $request){
 $inputs = $request->all(); // that will be take all inputs
 $your_model = Model::class // take your model to save data
 $your_model = store($inputs['image'],'name_of_your_link_folder');
 $your_model->create();
}
```

And for update image :

```
public fucntion create(Request $request){
 $inputs = $request->all(); // that will be take all inputs
 $your_model = Model::class // take your model to save data
 $your_model = store($inputs['image'],'name_of_your_link_folder');
 $your_model->save();
}
```

after this you need to use in your blade ( who you want to display image ) you just use this `{{ asset('storage'.$link_of_the_image }}`